# Use Node.js to parse JSON array that does not contain JSON objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, parsing

How can I parse this object using node.js?  I am trying to extract 3.25.  Thanks

```
"data": [["2020-05-04", 3.25],....]
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I got it.

data[0][1]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is much more suitable way to fetch data from your payload.

```
let val = {
    "data": [ [ "2020-05-04", 3.25 ], [ "2020-05-14", 1.25 ], [ "2020-02-04", 2.25 ]]
};

//-------------------------------

val["data"].forEach((element)=>{
    console.log(element[1]);
});

//-----------Or------------------

val["data"][0][1];
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is a great way to get any data field.  In my case, I simply needed the number in the first entry in huge JSON structure that was returned via a REST GET.